# Чем отличаются анонимные классы созданные на основе интерфейса и на основе класса в Java?

Tags: java, классы, inner, интерфейс

чем отличаются анонимные классы созданные на основе интерфейса и на основе класса в Java?

Comment: конструктором ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Анонимный класс согласно [JLS 15.9.5](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.9.5) представляют собой выражение, в котором объявление нового класса и его инициализация совмещены:

1. При объявлении класса будет создан новый класс, производный от указанного класса при использовании в качестве базы другого класса, или реализующий интерфейс при использовании в качестве базы интерфейса.
2. При инициализации будет создан новый объект и на него будет возвращения ссылка: анонимный класс является конкретным.

Таким образом, единственное отличие в анонимных классах, созданных на основе интерфейса и класса, заключается в количестве абстракных методов, которые необходимо реализовать.

Именно для этого для интерфейсов с большим количеством методов могут создаваться адаптеры с пустыми реализациями методов. Например, в Swing есть интерфейс [`MouseListener`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/event/MouseListener.html) и класс [`MouseAdapter`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/event/MouseAdapter.html).

Инициализации анонимного класса на основе интерфейса потребует реализации каждого метода, в то время как при инициализации анонимного класса на основе абстрактного/конкретного класса позволит изменить поведение за счет перегрузки методов и потребует реализации абстракных методов.

Answer (score 2):

Практически ничем.

То есть разница между

```
new BaseClass() { public void f() { /* ... */ } }
```

и

```
new BaseInterface() { public void g() { /* ... */ } }
```

такая же, как и между

```
class DerivedClass extends BaseClass
{
    public void f() { /* ... */ }
}
```

и

```
class DerivedClass implements BaseInterface
{
    public void g() { /* ... */ }
}
```

(отвлекаясь от того, что в первом случае у вас объекты, а во втором — классы).

Comment: Это больше похоже на C#, но суть та же.

Comment: @anber: Ой, точно. Перепутал. Сейчас исправлю.

Answer (score 2):

Не соглашусь с @VladD разница есть.

Например есть класс:

```
public abstract class RequestResult {

    public Exception getException() {
        return null;
    }

    public abstract String getResult();

}
```

Мы когда объявляем анонимный класс обязаны переопределить только абстрактный метод `getResult()`, `getException()` можем переопределить, можем нет.

```
public interface RequestResult {

    public Exception getException();

    public abstract String getResult();

}
```

В то же время для интерфейсы мы обязаны реализовать все методы, и более того если в базовом классе какие-то методы реализованы мы можем их использовать в анонимном.

Comment: Но это ведь не отличается от разницы между нормальным классом, наследующим другой класс, и классом, реализующим интерфейс, правильно?

Comment: @VladD не понял вопрос. По определению класс - это интерфейс+реализация. Интерфейс реализации не содержит. Если мы наследуемся от класса то часть реализации уже есть.